# Smarty automatic generate HTML table

Tags: php, html, html-table, smarty

I tried to make HTML table with Smarty but I can't. I have array (PHP) that look something like that (raw after print_r):

```
Array (
            [1] => Array (
                    [1] => Array (
                        [New York] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                [zone] => 7
                            )
                            [1] => Array (
                                [zone] => 2
                            )
                            [2] => Array (
                                [zone] => 1
                            )
                        )
                        [London] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                [zone] => 3
                            )
                            [1] => Array (
                                [zone] => 9
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
```

And this is my target(goal):

[image].

For now I just make only this:

```
<!--{foreach key=level_1_key item=level_1_val from=$items}-->
    <!--{foreach key=level_2_key item=level_2_val from=$level_1_val}-->
        <!--{foreach key=level_3_key item=level_3_val from=$level_2_val}-->
            <tr>
                <td><!--{$level_1_key}--></td>
                <td><!--{$level_2_key}--></td>
                <td><!--{$level_3_key}--></td>
            </tr>
        <!--{/foreach}-->
    <!--{/foreach}-->
<!--{/foreach}-->
```

I will be very grateful if someone give a advice how to make it.

Comment: from where you find out the array ?? with print_r ?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid its from my database.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid any idea how to make it?

Comment: use echo. and why all the php code comment out like html ??
foreach ending was not like that

Comment: @MostafaBaezid its smarty code

Comment: uppss sorry dnt know about that.. I always use raw .. Let me check on how smarty work. For you I will learn something new today. :)